# How to close a map and textbox

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Coronoa and Lua, and I'm trying to figure out how to close a map and textbox.  The map and text box appear over the home screen, and I was able to create a button (just a genreic black x) and make it close but I can not get the map or text box to close.  Below is the code snippet I am using, but I am stuck. I have searched Google, and read through their documentation, and I am just missing something.

```
 local obj = display.newImageRect( "closeButton.jpg" ,25,25 )
            obj.x = 60
            obj.y = 410     -- replaced with newImageRect for dynamic scaling (adjust X & Y as required)

    obj.touch = function (event)
             local btn = event.target
                if event.phase == "ended" then 
                btn.alpha = 0  -- example to show the function doing something
                myMap.alpha = 0
                textBox.alpha = 0
            end

    end

    -- begin detecting touches
    obj:addEventListener( "touch", obj.touch)

myMap = native.newMapView( 25, 0, 275, 180 )
myMap.mapType = "hybrid" -- other mapType options are "satellite" or "hybrid"
myMap.isScrollEnabled = true
myMap.isZoomEnabled = true 
myMap.isLocationUpdating = true
isVisible = myMap.isLocationVisible
myMap:setCenter( 38.354614, -81.726351 )
myMap:addMarker(  38.354614, -81.726351)
-- Adding the Text Box that contains the Directions
textBox = native.newTextBox( 22, 183, 280, 225 )
textBox.text = "blah blah blah boring directions."
local group = display.newGroup()
group:insert( obj )
```

I keep getting "attempt to index local 'myMap' (a nil value)", and the same error for textBox. So if anyone can help, its appreciated.

Comment: just locally declare your 'MapView' and 'textBox' above the 'obj.touch' function. (ie., add two lines 'local myMap;' and 'local textBox' above your function call)

Comment: So I did that and now it just gives me `attempt to index upvalue 'myMap' (a nil value)`

Comment: I think mapView is not supported in the simulator. Just refer this : http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/mapview

Comment: krs you are exactly right with both your comments.  My problem was, both those things.  I had my locals out of syntax, and I knew that the corona sim did not have the map, but I did not expect it to throw a nil error.  The reason it was throwing nil was because the map API was not there and it replaced it with a nil value. Thanks for the help. I would vote you up if I could, but you commented instead of answered :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locally declare your 'MapView' and 'textBox' above the 'obj.touch' function, as below:

```
 local myMap;
 local textBox;
```

**Note**: Corona mapView does not supported in the simulator.

Keep coding.................